# Show that the sup-norm is not derived from an inner product

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

I am trying to show that the norm $$\lVert{\cdot} \rVert _{\infty}=\sup_{t \in R}|x(t)|$$  does not come from an inner product (the norm is defined on all bounded and continuous real valued functions).

I tried to show that the inner product does not hold by using the conjugate symmetry, linearity and non-degenerancy conditions. But I am unsure of how to do it for the norm $\lVert{\cdot} \rVert _{\infty}$

Comment: Create a separate question for one of them.

Comment: Wouldn't the requirement "all bounded real valued functions" be sufficient? What does "continuous" add?

Comment: A norm from an inner product will satisfy [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), you just need to show you norm didn't.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: I tried to show that the inner product does not hold by using the conjugate symmetry, linearity and non-degenerancy conditions. But I am unsure of how to do it for the norm $\lVert{\cdot} \rVert _{\infty}$.

Comment: @Ora, hint: what are the sup-norms for $1$, $\cos t$ and their sums and differences?

Answer (score 10):

Explicit continuous functions that work on the unit interval (i.e. demonstrate the failure of the parallelogram law holding) are $f(x) = 1-x$ and $g(x) = x$.

$2||f||^2_\infty = 2$ and $2||g||^2_\infty = 2$, while $||f+g||^2_\infty = 1$ and $||f-g||^2_\infty = 1$.

Comment: But then, the functions in question are supposed to be bounded on $\mathbb R$. I agree that this is a nice example, but one needs to amend these functions slightly.

Comment: @Rhory_Ashworth has taken the domain as unit interval so we can take the values of the functions outside this unit interval as $0$.

Answer (score 4):

If the norm came from a scalar product, then the parallelogram law would hold.
But it is easy to find two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $$2||f||_\infty^2 + 2||g||_\infty^2 \neq ||f+g||_\infty^2 + ||f-g||_\infty^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

To simplify my answer, I'll ignore the "continuous" requirement and assume there is an appropriate inner product for that norm.

Let $b$ be a real number, $$f(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {1,}&{x = 0} \\ 
  {0,}&{x \ne 0} 
\end{array}} \right.$$
and $$g(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {1,}&{x = 2} \\ 
  {0,}&{x \ne 2} 
\end{array}} \right.$$

Then we would have $${\left\| {f + bg} \right\|^2} = {\left\| f \right\|^2} + {b^2}{\left\| g \right\|^2} + 2b\left\langle {f,g} \right\rangle $$

which varies quadratically for varying $b$. However, in our case, $\left\| {f + bg} \right\|$ is 1 for $\left| b \right| \leqslant 1$  ($f$ dominates) and is $\left| b \right|$ for $\left| b \right| > 1$ ($bg$ dominates). This is the wrong kind of variation, so the inner product must not exist.

You can easily make continuous functions $f$ and $g$ that behave similarly.

Comment: So you've shown that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ on the set of bounded functions cannot be induced by an inner product. What if $\|\cdot \|_\infty$ satisfies the paralleogram law on the smaller set of continuous, bounded functions? I'm not saying this is the case, but by dropping the requirement, you're making the proof not applicable for OPs question. You've built a counterexample which does not stem from the set in question - but I'm sure one can build a proper counterexample of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

> $\|u+v\|^2+\|u−v\|^2=2\|u\|^2+2\|v\|^2$

[the parallelogram identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJRSL.jpg)
the parallelogram identity is necessary and sufficient for a given norm to be derived from an inner product.

You can show that in your case it does not hold.